# execute adb shell command at runtime from the android application

Tags: android, shell, command, execute, adb

In my application I want to create a directory xyz in sdcard at the runtime from the my Application.

But it doesn't work.

Here is my code..

```
public class process extends Activity
{

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String[] str ={"mkdir","/sdcard/xyz"};

    try { 
        Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
        try {
            ps.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

}
}
```

Comment: You cannot, run **adb** shell commands from an application, as the adb shell is a shell obtained through the adb daemon.  At the moment you can run generic shell commands as an application user, but doing so is officially discouraged.  There are relatively few reasons to consider doing so, something that can be readily accomplished within your application process is definitely not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea if you can exec() scripts in Android, I strongly suspect you can't.

You don't need to to make a directory anyway. Do this:

> new File("/sdcard/xyz").mkdirs();

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for make directory in sdcard.

```
File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/xyz");
try{
    if(dir.mkDir()) {
        System.out.println("Directory created");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Directory is not created");
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStacktrace();
}
```

and add below uses-permission to android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```